# special comments and pre-processing

Tags: php, comments, caret, preprocessor

Is a comment of the form

```
/*:[url=users/%id]:*/
```

going to be a problem with any documentation toolkits out there (especially for PHP)? Or any other comment pre-preprocessors? (Related to http://code.google.com/p/caret/ )

Comment: Not sure, but your project looks interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by phpDoc, that shouldn't be a problem.

phpDoc reads from comments defined with a starting `/**`, not `/*`.

An example of a phpDoc comment entry would be:

```
/**
 * Description of this function
 * @param int Number in
 * @return int|string number or string out
 */
```

Which shouldn't clash with a comment that you have said.